# No puedo editar un flowDocument.xaml en la vista de diseño - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, xaml

Estoy tratando de crear y editar un *flowdocument.xaml* en *Visual Studio 2015* y me sale que no se puede editar dicho documento en la vista de diseño, me gustaría saber si a alguien más le ha pasado algo similar y si encontró una solución u otra alternativa de editor.

Anexo código:

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QodeskPOS.DefaultModule.Documents"
              ColumnWidth="400" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Georgia">
    <Paragraph>       
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas he probado tu ejemplo y lo puedo editar sin problema en la vista de diseño.
Entiendo que el `FlowDocument` lo has metido dentro de un control de tipo `Window`, `UserControl`... Si no es así ese es el problema que tienes.

Te dejo el ejemplo que me he creado yo:

```
 <Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QodeskPOS.DefaultModule.Documents"
    Title="FlowDocumentSample" Height="550" Width="500">
    <FlowDocument ColumnWidth="400" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Georgia">
        <Paragraph />
    </FlowDocument>
</Window>
```

Un saludo y espero que te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias Gerardo al parecer esa era la solución a mi problema , simplemente introduje el FlowDocument a un control de tipo Window y se pudo visualizar